# Xcode Autolayout vertical spacing constraint ambiguity warning where I don't see any ambiguity

Tags: storyboard, autolayout

I have the following constraints for a button view near the bottom of the screen:

Bottom Space to: Bottom Layout Guide >= 10  -- priority = 1000

**Bottom Space to: Bottom Layout Guide >= 30  -- priority = 750**

Bottom Space to: Bottom Layout Guide = 60  -- priority = 250

It says the middle one (in bold) is an Inequality Constraint Ambiguity.  To me it seems like it should simply scale: first choice = 60, second choice = 30, minimum = 10.  Or more like: iPad = 60, newer iPhone = 30, older iPhone 10.

I have some other similar constraints that aren't warnings.  Some scale exactly as I think they should, some don't give me a warning but they also never take the first choice even when there is room enough for it without violating any other constraints.

Does anyone know why this is an error, or how to scale the way I want?

Comment: Can you please add some snaps of constraints you set?

Answer (score 0):

Here was the problem.  I had a lot of vertical spacing all with the same priorities.  There was a thread of vertical spaces from the top of the view down each sub-view to the bottom of the view all using this first-choice, second-choice, third-choice system.  All had priority 1000 for the third choice, 750 for second choice, 250 for first choice.

Even though they each had 3 choices and the 3rd choice for all would have made the view fit in the smallest iPhone.  It was a conflict to use the same priority for all those spaces.  I had to make 1 space be 1000 for third choice, 751 for second choice, 251 for first choice.  Another space had to be 1000, 752, 252.  So the autolayout could determine who gets their second choice and who gets their first choice, etc.  If they couldn't all get their first choice.

I hope this makes sense.